# How to get multiple value of select2 without using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

I have select element using select2 with multiple values, I try to get the return values something below

```
elem = ['apple', 'grapes'];
```

Html code:

```
<select name="fruits" class="select2 mb-3 select2-multiple" style="width: 100%" multiple="multiple"
    data-placeholder="Choose">
    <optgroup label="Fruits">
        <option value="apple">Apple</option>
        <option value="banana">Banana</option>
        <option value="grapes">Grapes</option>
        <option value="Durian">Durian</option>
        <option value="watermelon">Watermelon</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

I have tried to get the data by getElementsByName.

```
const elem = document.getElementsByName('fruits').value;
```

but get undefined

can anyone help me?

Comment: Select2 is designed for use with jQuery. If you're not using jQuery, I doubt that you even have a Select2.

Comment: why does it need to be done without jQuery? Select2 uses jQuery; so it should already be in your codebase. Not sure why did you ask the solution without jQuery.

Comment: ...and since you don't seem to have a Select2 in the first place, your question is "how to retrieve the selected values of an HTML select element" and this has been answered many many times here, take a look.

Comment: the reason why I don't want to use jquery because my code will be bundle up using parcel js

Comment: I have solved the problem. thanks